# Simulate null parameters in Freemarker macros

Tags: freemarker

I'm building a site using Freemarker and have started heavily using macros.  I know in Freemarker 2.3 that passing a null value into a macro as a parameter is equivalent to not passing a parameter at all so I've created a global variable called "null" to simulate null checking in my macros:

```
<#assign null="NUL" />
```

Now in my macros I can do this:

```
<#macro doSomething param1=null>
  <#if param1 != null>
    <div>WIN!</div>
  </#if>
</#macro>
```

The problem comes if I want to pass a parameter that isn't a scalar. For instance, passing a List (which in Freemarker is a SimpleSequence) to a macro and checking against my null keyword yields the error:

> freemarker.template.TemplateException:
> The only legal comparisons are between
> two numbers, two strings, or two
> dates. Left  hand operand is a
> freemarker.template.SimpleSequence
> Right hand operand is a
> freemarker.template.SimpleScalar

I took a look at the freemarker code and I can see the issue (ComparisonExpression.isTrue()):

```
if(ltm instanceof TemplateNumberModel && rtm instanceof TemplateNumberModel) { 
  ...
}
else if(ltm instanceof TemplateDateModel && rtm instanceof TemplateDateModel) {
  ...
}
else if(ltm instanceof TemplateScalarModel && rtm instanceof TemplateScalarModel) {
  ...
}
else if(ltm instanceof TemplateBooleanModel && rtm instanceof TemplateBooleanModel) {
  ...
}
// Here we handle compatibility issues
else if(env.isClassicCompatible()) {
  ...
}
else {
  throw new TemplateException("The only legal comparisons...", env);
}
```

So the only solution I can think of is to set isClassicCompatible to true, which I think will call toString() on both objects and compare the result.  However, the documentation specifically says anything relying on old features should be rewritten.

My quesion is, is there a solution to this that doesn't rely on deprecated features?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `null` reference is by design an error in FreeMarker. Defining a custom null value - which is a string - is not a good idea for the reasons you mention. The following constructs should be used instead:

- Macro and function parameters can have a default value, so the callers can omit them
- To check if a variable is `null`, you should use the `??` operator: `<#if (name??)>`
- When you use a variable that can be `null`, you should use the `!` operator to specify a default value: `name!"No name"`
- To check if a sequence (or a string) is empty, use the `?has_content` builtin: `<#if (names?has_content)>`

You can specify an empty sequence as default parameter value in a macro, and simply test whether it's empty.

Comment: I didn't mention any reasons defining a custom null value would be a bad idea and none of your suggestions help me in a case where I want to pass in a list as a parameter and give it a default empty value.

Comment: @Cameron: Specifying an empty list as default parameter value is precisely one of the items in my answer. The other items can help you deal with undefined variables. Try and understand the answers before you deem them inappropriate.

Comment: your answer didn't address the question, it just said "that's not a good idea" without any reason. It wouldn't matter if I supplied an empty list as a default value because you can't compare lists in Freemarker. Your third bullet is effectively repeating your first one.  And your second bullet tells me how to do a null check but since parameters can't be null inside a macro, it isn't a solution.

Comment: @Cameron: You can easily check if a sequence is empty with `?has_content` (http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_has_content), so you can easily use an empty sequence as default parameter value.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.  If you edit your answer with this solution, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Cameron: I edited my answer, but still fail to see the exact relation with your question (i.e. what with `classicCompatible`?).

Comment: I basically needed a way to check whether or not a parameter was passed in (ie; whether the argument was null) but I couldn't just check <#if var == ""> because if var is a list, it would blow up.  I didn't know about ?has_content, which is just like checking if var is an empty string but works on all data types.  I'm actually going to use my personal solution, but I think your answer is more correct because it is out-of-the-box.

Comment: Not sure how using a built-in feature "out-of-the-box".  It seems your solution essentially recreates ?has_content, except that it's less efficient, less flexible, and requires more typing.

Answer (score 11):

Here's what I did, which seems to work in most scenarios:

The default value should be an **empty string**, and the null-check should be **?has_content**.

```
<#macro someMacro optionalParam="" >
    <#if (optionalParam?has_content)>
        <#-- NOT NULL -->
    <#else>
        <#-- NULL -->
    </#if>
</#macro>
```

Comment: Thank you for saving my afternoon time ;)

Answer (score 3):

A coworker has suggested a null-checking function may be the most elegant solution:

```
<#assign null="NUL" />

<#function is_null variable>
  <#if variable?is_string & variable == null>
    <#return true />
  <#else>
    <#return false />
  </#if>
</#function>
```

Running with that idea, I found another possible solution in the [mailing list](http://freemarker.624813.n4.nabble.com/How-to-add-custom-method-using-built-in-like-syntax-td3081132.html), which is to create a null-checking function in Java by extending TemplateMethodModelEx.  I can then insert it directly into my model map and have it globally available in all my templates.  The resulting Freemarker code is pretty clean:

```
<#maco doSomething param1=null>
  <#if !is_null(param1)>
    <div>WIN!</div>
  </#if>
</#macro>
```

This seems to be the best way to simulate null parameters inside a macro.

Comment: I would recommend using a custom TemplateModel implementation as the null value and a TemplateMethodModelEx for checking if a the value passed in is an instance of that custom class. This is basically the same as above, but there can't be clashes with a string that happens to be "NUL", and it's faster (if that matters). The null value and the checker method could be added to the `freemarker.template.Configuration` as "shared variable" for convenience. Of course, the catch is that passing this value to a method will not pass a Java null, nor Java method returns values will be converted...

Comment: Thanks! I am going to use this solution, although I marked the other answer as correct because it was an out-of-the-box solution.  This will really clean up our Freemarker macros.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it's not a scalar first:

```
<#if !param1?is_scalar || param1 != null)>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution that may fit to your need.

```
<#macro el user={}>
...
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName"
                                       value="${(user.identity.firstName)!''}">
...
</#macro>
```

I define a default empty object `{}` instead of null to avoid 2 big if else block in my element.

make sure that when you give a default value to the attribute (firstName in my case), to put the parenthesis to all the expression then the ! sign.

So whatever `identity` is undefined or `firstName` is undefined, freemarker use the default value

```
(user.identity.firstName)!''
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i do not understand why null's are not allowed. I have a java function to retrieve a specific image URL with given optional / nullable parameters like *height*.

I wrote a macro for it using following workaround:

**Java function**

```
/**
 * Converts the given value to <code>null</code> if it equals the default
 * value, else returns it directly.
 *
 * @param value
 * @param defaultValue
 *
 * @return
 */
public static Object nullIfDefault(final Object value, final Object defaultValue)
{
    if (value != null && value.equals(defaultValue))
        return null;
    return value;
}

/**
 * Converts the given value to <code>null</code> if it equals an empty
 * string, else returns it directly.
 *
 * @param value
 *
 * @return
 */
public static Object nullIfEmpty(final Object value)
{
    return ObjectUtils.nullIfDefault(value, "");
}
```

**Macro**

Import static function

```
<#assign ObjectUtils=statics['com.example.ObjectUtils']/>

<#macro compEntityImage imageRetriever entity height="" width="">

    <img src="${imageRetriever.getMediaFileUrl(entity, 
        ObjectUtils.nullIfEmpty(height), 
        ObjectUtils.nullIfEmpty(width))}">

</#macro>
```

**Markup**

```
<@compEntityImgage imageRetriever=imageRetriver entity=product height=500/>
```