# Freemarker Default Value if NULL

Tags: freemarker

I'm using Freemarker 2.3.20 with JDK 7.

When ever I'm defining a value in my template that results in NULL at run time, it gives me an error.
I understand there are many ways to handle this error as mentioned in answers like this one: [Simulate null parameters in Freemarker macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553004/simulate-null-parameters-in-freemarker-macros)

But what I want is a global solution. My freemarker template has 'hundreds' of fields that any of them could be null at any given time. Instead of writing a function to call to handle for nulls, or setting a default value for null with the exclamation mark '!', etc; Is there a way to define something global in the freemarker configurations, or overwrite some java class, such that: all null fields will return 'NULL' or a particular user defined value.

Comment: You can create your own `TemplateExceptionHandler` that prints some default values in case of null-s.

Comment: Isn't it a problem only at specific places, like where you print the value of form fields (just an example), or something like that? Is this only about `${...}` at all? What value should be displayed there then?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `<#setting classic_compatible=true>` in .ftl file or add

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(); cfg.setClassicCompatible(true);
```

in your code.