# Minimum arguments for variable parameters in freemarker macros

Tags: macros, freemarker

When you have variable parameters in a macro, for instance

```
 <#macro m a b c...>
```

Do you have to pass a minimum of 3 arguments or 2 while calling the macro? Does the parameter `c` here have to have at least 1 value? Also is there any way to specify a parameter as null by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have variable parameters in a macro, you don't have to pass a value for the last argument.

For example:

```
<#macro m a b c...>
    a = ${a!}
    b = ${b!}
    <#list c?keys as attr>
    ${attr} = ${c[attr]}
    </#list>
</#macro>

<@m a='A' b='B' />

<@m a='A' b='B' c='C' d='D'/>
```

Will output:

```
a = A
b = B


a = A
b = B
c = C
d = D
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<#macro name param1 param2 ... paramN>
  ...
  <#nested loopvar1, loopvar2, ..., loopvarN>
  ...
  <#return>
  ...
</#macro>
```

Where:

- name: name of macro variable. It's not an expression. It follows the
  same syntax as like top-level variable references, like myMacro or
  my-macro. However, it can also be written as a string literal, which
  is useful if the macro name contains characters that can't be
  specified in an identifier, for example <#macro "foo~bar">.... Note
  that this string literal does not expand interpolations (as
  "${foo}").
- param1, param2, ...etc.: the name of the local variables store the
  parameter values (not expression), optionally followed by = and the
  default value (that's an expression). The default value can even be
  another parameter, for example <#macro section title label=title>.
  The parameter name uses the same syntax as like top-level variable
  references, so the same features and restrictions apply.
- paramN, the last parameter may optionally has 3 trailing dots (...),
  which indicates that the macro takes a variable number of parameters
  and the parameters that doesn't match any other parameters will be
  collected in this last parameter (also called the catch-all
  parameter). When the macro is called with named parameters, paramN
  will be a hash containing all of the undeclared key/value pairs
  passed to the macro. When the macro is called using positional
  parameters, paramN will be the sequence of the extra parameter
  values. (Inside the macro, to find out which was the case, you can
  use myCatchAllParam?is_sequence.)

**Therefore as you can see macro does not have any limitation to take N parameters.**

This structure creates a macro variable (in the current namespace, if you know namespace feature). If you are new to macros and [user-defined directives](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_userDefined.html) you should read the the tutorial about user-defined directives.

Macro variable stores a template fragment (called **macro definition body**) that can be used as user-defined directive. The variable also stores the name of allowed parameters to the user-defined directive. **You must give value for all of those parameters when you use the variable as directive, except for parameters that has a default value. The default value will be used if and only if you don't give value for the parameter when you call the macro.**

The variable will be created at the beginning of the template; it does not mater where the macro directive is placed in the template.

Example: Macro with parameters:

```
<#macro test foo bar baaz>
  Test text, and the params: ${foo}, ${bar}, ${baaz}
</#macro>
<#-- call the macro: -->
<@test foo="a" bar="b" baaz=5*5-2/>
```

> Output:

```
 Test text, and the params: a, b, 23
```

Example: Macro with parameters and default parameter values:

```
<#macro test foo bar="Bar" baaz=-1>
  Test text, and the params: ${foo}, ${bar}, ${baaz}
</#macro>
<@test foo="a" bar="b" baaz=5*5-2/>
<@test foo="a" bar="b"/>
<@test foo="a" baaz=5*5-2/>
<@test foo="a"/>
```

> Output:

```
  Test text, and the params: a, b, 23
  Test text, and the params: a, b, -1
  Test text, and the params: a, Bar, 23
  Test text, and the params: a, Bar, -1
```

However, about last part of your question there is an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553004/simulate-null-parameters-in-freemarker-macros):

The null reference is by design an error in FreeMarker. Defining a custom null value - which is a string - is not a good idea for the reasons you mention. The following constructs should be used instead:

- Macro and function parameters can have a default value, so the
  callers can omit them
- To check if a variable is null, you should use the ?? operator: <#if
  (name??)>
- When you use a variable that can be null, you should use the !
  operator to specify a default value: name!"No name"
- To check if a sequence (or a string) is empty, use the ?has_content
  builtin: <#if (names?has_content)>

You can specify an empty sequence as default parameter value in a macro, and simply test whether it's empty.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer, but I'm talking about macros in freemarker

Comment: @AnnMathews Yes, I modified that, hope it will be helpful for you

Comment: But if I have variable parameters, like `paramN` in your answer, do I have to give a value for it? Or can I ignore it in some cases?

Comment: You must give value for all of those parameters when you use the variable as directive(as I referred you to read User-defined directive definition, directive is specified by @, in my case test is variable and its parameters must take value when test uses as @test), except for parameters that have a default value!